# Gerador de tabelas GOTO e ACTION

Tags: java, c++, parser

Em relação a Analisador Sintático LR, temo a seguinte Wiki:

http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analisador_sint%C3%A1tico_LR#Algoritmo

Nela existe um algoritmo canônico para gerar as tabelas GOTO e ACTION.

Procurei, e não encontrei algum software que tenha implementado esse algoritmo, para que se possa usar didaticamente.

Algum software que a partir de uma gramática, gere algo semelhante a:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Enquanto entendo que o [Beaver](http://beaver.sourceforge.net/) é um *super set* do que você precisa, acho que vale a pena dar uma olhada. Ele gera classes Java a partir de gramáticas em EBNF. As classes são uma representação das tabelas de lookup. A ferramenta também gera todo um esquema com *delegates* para as ações. Combinado a um gerador de analisadores léxicos como o [JFlex](http://www.jflex.de/) você tem tudo o que precisa para aulas de compiladores.

Comment: Olá. Dei uma olhada no que comentou. Não é bem isso que estou procurando. Para isso teria o JFlex e o Bayac. Procuro um programa com interface gráfica, onde possa a partir de uma gramática, gerar as tabelas GOTO e ACTION. No caso seria as tabelas shift-recude

Comment: Entendi, até onde vai meu conhecimento, acredito que não exista um programa (ainda mais com UI) apenas para gerar uma representação das tabelas. Talvez você tenha que escrever algo você mesmo. O mais próximo que encontrei disso foi esse Applet [SR Parsing Demo](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~zdu/parsdemo/srframe.html) que, para ser honesto, nem roda na versão do Java que tenho instalado.

Comment: Obrigado. Continuo a procura.

Comment: Parece que a ferramenta [JFLAP](http://www.jflap.org/whatis.html), entre muitas outras coisas, incorporou o [jeLLRap](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~rodger/tools/jellrap/) e é capaz de gerar umas visualizações bem bacanas. Talvez valha a pena dar uma olhada, pelo menos para tomar como base.